# What is the mechanism behind duplicate removal in java Collections (e.g LinkedHashSet)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, set

Can someone please explain to me how the code below works? The objective is to remove the duplicate values in array . I understand part of it but not entirely

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class ArrayExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws `CloneNotSupportedException`
    {
        //Array with duplicate elements
        Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,1,3,5};

        //This array has duplicate elements
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(numbers) );

        //Create set from array elements
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>( Arrays.asList(numbers) );

        //Get back the array without duplicates
        Integer[] numbersWithoutDuplicates = linkedHashSet.toArray(new Integer[] {});

        //Verify the array content
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(numbersWithoutDuplicates) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: A set automatically removes duplicates. A LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order.

Answer (score 4):

`HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` is so implemented, that it prevents duplicate objects. Here, you are creating one passing list to the constructor, so that resulting set has only distinct elements. It uses `hashCode` and `equals` on collision.

Comment: hi thanks , but my doubt is "LinkedHashSet<Integer> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>( Arrays.asList(numbers) );" line onwards ; can you please explain me exactly what this code is doing ?

Comment: You are passing a `List` to the constructor of `HashSet`

Answer (score 1):

`Set` in Java tries to recreate mathematical sets which are collections of elements which cannot be duplicate. What you are doing is creating an Array `numbers` with duplicates, then creating a `LinkedHashSet` (which is a kind of `HashSet`, which is a kind of `Set`) with this Array. The Set contains all Elements of the Array and since it is a set, there are no duplicates. Then you just convert this set to an Array which possibly has a different order and no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The Set interface is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. 
 see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html for more details. An example implementation is the HashSet and the LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashSet` extends from `HashSet`,and `HashSet` realy use `HashMap` to store elements.The `Map` in java require the key must be unique,repeat key will covering.